# how do I create a web app skeleton using flatiron node framework?

Tags: javascript, node.js, flatiron.js

I see documentation here http://flatironjs.org/ to create a app skeleton. The command specified is,

```
flatiron create <type> <app-name>
```

But I do not see any values for the "type". I tried http and it did not work. Any inputs appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the documentation may be slightly out of sync with the current code. For now as far as I can tell the correct command line command is:

```
flatiron create <app-name>
```

This creates a cli skeleton app and for a web app you will have to make some changes to your app.js file along the lines of the http-sample.js file which you can find at:

https://github.com/flatiron/flatiron/tree/master/examples

You will also need to add union to your package dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The cmd : `flatiron create <app-name>` will actually by default generate the a http app skeleton. If you enter `flatiron create --help` on the cli you'll get:

`help:    Generates a flatiron skeleton application. If no <type>

help:    is specified an HTTP application will be created.

help:    <type> can currently be either cli or http

help:

help:    create <app-name> <type>`